# Java: version conflicts with WS

Tags: java

I have a JRE application. My dev-environment is 1.9, the target is 1.7.
It is managed with maven.

If my maven source and target is 8 then I get this error if I start the program at the target.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MYPRG/Server/Server : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

It appears at the very beginning.

Thats ok I think. My target is an older than the dev.
So I changed to 7 in my pom.xml for target and source (also tried 1.7).

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/xml/ws/spi/ProviderImpl : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Now the error occurs not at the very beginning but if I instance some JNI I think. I did not expect that.

Whats the reason and how can I overcome it (without updating the target)?

Comment: Maybe you have a dependency compiled with > 1.7 When the execution reaches that dependency code it raises exception.

Comment: @EugenCovaci would that be com/sun/xml/ws/spi/ProviderImpl?

Comment: @keuleJ Could be.

Comment: That was my idea too but I am pretty new to maven. Do I find that out in the maven repository? The strategy is then take an older version of the dependency?

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:tree` to have the list of all dependencies. If there are few, check them one by one. Otherwise use an IDE, maybe it gives you a hint. About the strategy, downgrading is not that simple.

Comment: The tree gives me the dependencies. But where do I see what version of a dependency is good for what version of JRE?